# Is there a best practice regarding where to register a PeriodicWorkRequest?

Tags: android, periodic-task

Currently I have the code below in my MainActivity.onCreate() method.
What's the best practice about where I should register my PeriodicWorkRequests?

Thank you

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PeriodicWorkRequest uploadLogsRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(UploadLogsRequest.class, PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();
    WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(uploadLogsRequest);
}
```